# why this bash script (flow control if else) doesn't work

Tags: bash

```html
setjdk() 
{
     if ["$1" == "a"]
         then echo "A"
     elif ["$1" == "b"];
         then echo "B"
     else
        echo "Cow"
     fi 
       
}
```

The above bash function aims to output different result based on the first given parameter value. However, when it doesn't work as expected. when I type in "setjdk a", i got the following result:

-bash: [a: command not found
-bash: [a: command not found
Cow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is a command. Commands need whitespace between their arguments.

```
[ "$1" == "a" ]
```